# Using REST API on Neo4J

Tags: rest, neo4j

I installed Neo4J locally and populated a sample database.  I can view it just fine on the Neo4J browser.  I can view the Service root at http://localhost:7474/db/data/.

I see these two links:

```
relationship_index  /db/data/index/relationship
node_index  /db/data/index/node
```

But when I click on them, nothing happens.

Does some web server also need to be running locally?

My neo4j-server.properties has thi set:
    org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri=/db/data/

Is that "/db/data" value totally arbitrary (ie, it can be whatever)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those URLs are the root resources for referring to nodes and relationships by index. For example:

```
http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/1
```

refers to the node with an id of `1`. More information is available in [the manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api.html).